# In Corda, what should `PartyAndReference.reference` be set to?

Tags: corda

When defining a `FungibleAsset` in Corda, you need to provide an `issuer` reference in the form of a `PartyAndReference`.

`PartyAndReference` is a combination of:

- `party: AbstractParty`, the on-ledger identity of the party issuing the asset
- `reference: OpaqueBytes`

What should this `reference: OpaqueBytes` field be set to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaDocs state that the `reference` field is supposed to represent "something being stored or issued by a party e.g. in a vault or (more likely) on their normal ledger".

However, if two `FungibleAsset` states have different `reference` fields but are otherwise completely identical, they are no longer considered fungible. This is because there is no logic provided for combining the different `reference` fields into a single combined `reference` field.

This feature will likely be redesigned in the future. In the short-run, I'd advise setting this field to a dummy value shared across all of the fungible assets you issue, such as `OpaqueBytes.of(0)`.